# copy array of vectors

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

What is the best way to copy a std::array of vectors?

I have an array like this:

```
std::array< std::vector<std::vector<IK::Point_3>>, 2> m0;
std::array< std::vector<std::vector<IK::Point_3>>, 2> m1;
```

I see that the code works by simply writing `m1=m0;`

Before I was writing all the time the copy operation, which for sure long to write down and is much more slower.

```
for (int i = 0; i < m0.size(); i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < m0[i].size(); j++) {
        m1[i].emplace_back(std::vector<IK:Point_3>());
        m1[i].back().reserve(m0[i].size());
        for (auto& p : m0[i][j])
            m1.back().emplace_back(p);
    }
}
```

Is there any case where I should not use equals sign, and copy data like the one in the for loop?
And is there a better way for copying?

Comment: just do assignment: `m1 = m0;`. this is one of advantages of `std::array` over c-array.

Comment: It is unlikely that you will come up with a better way to assign a `std::array` than the array's assignment operator.

Comment: *Before I was writing all the time the copy operation,* -- This is why you should always consult the documentation.  [std::array](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).  There may be other functions you're writing "by hand" that are already provided by `std::array`.